# Bullets won't shoot out of barrel in top-down shooter

Tags: java, rotation, shooter

So I am working on a top down shoot and have been stumped on why my bullets refuse to come out of the barrel of the gun. I know about the rotation equation which is

```
x2 = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta)
y2 = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta)
```

Here is part of my shoot method for my shotgun

```
    float dx = (float) (5 * Math.cos(direction) + 40 * Math.sin(direction));
    float dy = (float) (5 * -Math.sin(direction) + 40 * Math.cos(direction));

    //PlayState.effects.add(new MuzzleFlashEffect(x + dx, y + dy, (float) Math.toDegrees(-direction)));

    for(int i = 0; i < randNum; i++){
        float var = MathUtils.random(-accuracy, accuracy);
        float dir = direction + (float) Math.toRadians(var);
        PlayState.projectiles.add(new Bullet(this, x + dx, y + dy, dir));
    }

    bulletsInClip--;
    lastShot = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The bullets always tend to shoot out of the left side and I don't have a clue why. The player sprite origin is the center and not the top left but I can't get it shooting out of the barrel.

[image]

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can fix this. I have spent too many hours and losing my sanity.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here are some pictures of the character shooting in different directions

**RIGHT**
[image: RIGHT]

**LEFT**
[image]

**DOWNWARD**
[image]

Comment: What does it look like if the player is shooting in a different direction - to the left/right, or downwards?

Comment: can you verify that the sprite is in the correct location, add a rectangle with the bounding box of the player and make sure they match up. my guess would be that the sprite is drawn in the wrong location

Comment: Added some pictures to show you guys in more detail what it looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what is happening.

```
float dx = (float) (5 * Math.cos(direction) + 40 * Math.sin(direction));
float dy = (float) (5 * -Math.sin(direction) + 40 * Math.cos(direction));
```

So facing right, dx = 40, so cos(direction) = 0 sin(direction) = 1.

dy = -5 for the same reasons.  0,0 is top left.

This means that direction = pi/2.  This is unusual, normally pi/2 means up in java.

Facing down the shots are offset downward and a little left. 
So cos(direction) = 1, sin(direction) = 0, dx = -5, dy = 40.  This means the angle is 0.

So far so good, though the angle is still funny, 0 meaning down.

Facing left it's down and below.

dx = -40, dy = 5. cos(direction) = 0, sin(direction) = -1, so this is -pi/2

Then up, it's greatly to the left and up.

What I would expect given the rest is that direction = pi. sin(direction) = 0, cos(direction) = -1

If that is the case, then you should have dx = -5, dy = -40.

But you have something that looks more like dy = -80, dx = -40.

So what's up?

My first test would be to check what exactly the direction is when you're pointing up.

Then I would watch the values of dx and dy to confirm that they were in fact the things that were screwing up and it wasn't something like your x and y values that were getting offset when you pointed up.

I know there's no way for both cos(x) and sin(x) to return positive numbers, and no way for cos(x) to return something less than -1.

So either something is screwing up the value of dy (like code that isn't shown) or the value of y when you create the bullets is incorrect, or possibly that there's some logic in your bullet constructor that is screwing up the position in that case.

I would look at the bullet constructor to make sure that it's not the one at fault. Finally I would worry about the casts to float. All the trig functions take and return doubles, and conversions to floats can do weird things which might be present elsewhere.

Comment: As a small note, there are many ways for cos(x) and sin(x) to both return positive numbers; for instance, cos(pi/4) = sin(pi/4) ~= .707.

Comment: I fixed it and I appreciate the time you put in helping me. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenStadnicki or more precisely all `0 < x < pi/2` will have both `sin(x)` and `cos(x)` be positive